# Disconnecting a resistor out of parallel with a switch

Tags: resistors, switches, dc-motor

I'm modifying an existing circuit. In order to perform this modification, I need to tap a resistor in the circuit and put another in parallel. By connecting this resistor in parallel (changing the resistance of the existing resistor) it will alter the circuit. Removing it, puts it back the way it was.

My question is this: If I connect the resistor to a switch, do I need to disconnect both legs of the resistor to remove it from the circuit or only a single leg (double pole switch vs single pole switch)? Is it relevant that this resistor is in a motor circuit that may have sine wave frequency running across it?

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to EE.SE! Electronic engineers speak in the language of schematics. If you click on edit and the schematic symbol, a schematic editor will open. Please draw what you have.

Answer (score 1):

Usually disconnecting one end of the resistor and leaving the other connected is fine.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fww7Vh.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

with one end disconnected the resistor will not participate in the current flow through the circuit

Comment: This is the appropriate diagram. However, I believe that the first commentor made the point that I was asking about wherein if R1 is part of an IC circuit that is part of a frequency generator the leg from the wire to the open switch and the leg through R2 would carry different loads. This may have an effect on the wave itself as the current across R1 is not unidirectional?

Comment: the switch blocks current in both directions

Comment: at very high frequencies the unterminated end may be significant. but in the general case it will not.

Comment: According to the service manual for the device, the distance between wave peaks would vary between 75 and 225 ms. I would presume that increasing this resistance would increase the speed of the wave (as this makes the motor spin faster). What would be considered a 'high frequency' for 5-17v, 56k ohm resistance?

Comment: When  I said "very high frequency", i meant like VHF  30MHz and up. For 75 milliseconds you had best keep ypur wires shorter than about 2000 km :*)

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the voltage, current, and frequency of the signal going through the resistors is relevant.  For example, if you are simply changing the brightness of an LED, then a SPST switch will be fine.  If you are modifying one leg of an RF attenuator, then a SPST switch will create an unterminated stub that could be a real problem for the downstream circuits.

Without knowing more about the load, this is a guess:

Assuming the motor is DC or powerline AC (50-60 Hz), a SPST switch should be fine.  For better long-term reliability, use a switch with contacts rated for at least twice the expected breaking current.

Comment: That's what I suspected. It would be a leg off an IC the is part of the frequency generation for a motor. I can't see inside the IC so I'm not entirely sure what it's doing but I was suspecting that the issue I'm having is that stray leg making for an odd wave.

Comment: Part Number - ???????